# How to solve Boolean expression to print result in a particular manner.?

Tags: java, boolean

Assume I have a Boolean expression `(T && (F || T))` because of `&&` operator the result depends on the value of first `T` so I want to print a string `"1XX"`. 1 for true and `X` represents rest of `Boolean` values don't matter. Like for expression `((T && F) || F)`, it should print `"X00"` as all `Boolean` values matter.

Comment: So you need a boolean expression parser.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not reproducible and not a concrete programming question. As a hint, for your task I suggest you study compilers (in particular how to parse your boolean expression grammar).